# How to get certain part of object array as a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an Object array:

```
let products = [{ code: 'a', num: 1 }, { code: 'b', num: 2 }];
```

I want to get the **codes** array: `['a', 'b']`.

This is how I am doing now using **lodash**:

```
let codes = [];
_.forEach(products, (product) => {
  codes.push(product.code);
});
```

Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) for lodash:

```
let codes = _.map(products, 'code');
```

```js
let products = [{ code: 'a', num: 1 }, { code: 'b', num: 2 }];

let codes = _.map(products, 'code');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(codes, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, there is a pure JavaScript solution:

```
let codes = products.map(obj => obj.code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vanilla JavaScript `Array.map`

```
var arr = [{ code: 'a', num: 1 }, { code: 'b', num: 2 }];

var newArr = arr.map(function(obj){
  return obj.code;

})

console.log(newArr)
```

```js
   var arr = [{
     code: 'a',
     num: 1
   }, {
     code: 'b',
     num: 2
   }];

   var newArr = arr.map(function(obj) {
     return obj.code;

   })

    console.log(newArr)
```